# How to record a live show through a mixer with a scarlett 2i2

Tags: recording, live, mixer

I want to record live shows which usually mainly includes 1 or 2 guitars and vocals. I have a Scarlett 2i2 audio interface and the mixer is a Hybrid SM802MS. What would be the best way of doing this? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish your goal.

**Here is what I would try first.**  Connect the SM802MS to the Scarlett 2i2 audio interface using a 1/4 inch male TRS to Dual Male RCA Cable like the one pictured here:

[image: Male TRS to 2 male RCA]

Connect the RCA pins to the RCA output jacks on the top right of your mixer.  Be sure to use the output vs. the input.  Plug the TRS plug into either one of the Neutrik Combo Insert Sockets on the Scarlett 2i2.  Set the LINE/INST switch next to the socket to LINE to tell the 2i2 that you are using a TRS balanced plug vs. a standard TS instrument cable.

After you have connected the mixer to the interface, set your gain control on the 2i2 to prevent clipping.  Now you should be all set to record the signal from your mixer into your DAW on the computer you connect via USB to the 2i2 interface.

**Another option** would be to use the headphone out on the mixer to connect to the 2i2 interface using a TRS male to TRS male connector.  Everything related to the 2i2 interface is the same.  The only difference is how you connect the other end of the cable to the mixer.  Be sure to set the headphone volume at no more than half way.

**The third option** - if you aren't using your control room out sockets on the mixer for sending the signal to stage monitors or a control room, is to use a cable like the one pictured below to connect to your interface via the control room out sockets:

[image: 1/4 inch TRS to 2 - 1/4 inch TS]

**EDIT:** It is not common to attempt to create a stereo image in a live mix since only the audience sitting between the two mains stacks or speakers would benefit and the audience to the left and right of center would miss part of the sound on stage. But if you are using stereo effects in your live mix and you want to capture those effects in your recording, you could use a Dual Male RCA Cable to Dual Male 1/4 inch TS cable (pictured below) and plug one 1/4 inch TS plug into each of the two input sockets on the interface.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by connecting the stereo output (both L and R) of the mixer to one single input in the interface? Why not connect output 1 of the mixer to input 1 of the interface, and output 2 of the mixer to input 2 of the interface (using a dual RCA cable with two TS converters)? Balanced and stereo are not the same thing. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @JCPedroza  The 2 inputs on the interface are not left/right stereo channels but rather two separate channels to allow for inputting 2 sources simultaneously.  If you were outputting a stereo signal from the mixer you could send the left channel to one of the two channels on the interface and right to the other.  But OP stated he is mixing two guitars and vocal.  Neither guitar or vocal mic will have a left right stereo input as would a keyboard or electronic drum module or mp3 or CD player.  Also - goal is to record live show.  Not going to pan guitars to left or right in a live setting.

Comment: Guitars and vocal are not stereo in the input, but they might at the output. Maybe through panning, maybe through effects. That's why you want to capture both L and R separately. Keep it flexible, live mixes are often stereo.

Comment: @JCPedroza if the input is mono, then there's no reason to have an L and R channels. You can easily pan and add effects on one channel and if you really wanted to have two separate mixes for effects or anything else you can handle it from the mixer. The presonus board I use can split an input into two channels software wise, but even in a simple mixer you could link it pre effects or panning and at that point it's really two diffrent instruments not L and R. At that point why stop at two when you can have 11?

Comment: @Dom You have 3 mono inputs, but the mix is stereo. What the asker wants to capture is the mix. For that you need to capture both L and R separately. If you record using the first suggestion you merge L and R, losing the stereo image. There's all the reason in the world to have L and R channels, you can't just "unmerge" it later.

Comment: @JCPedroza then you have stereo inputs not mono. Th interface shouldn't change the mix of the inputs either. Calling a mono input L or R makes no senses as you don't magically have stereo signals. You can send a mono input signal to a stereo out just fine. Sure it's not the same as stereo, but it works.

Comment: @Dom Stereo inputs? What are you talking about? Take two mono inputs, pan one slightly left, the other slightly right. Done. You have two mono inputs and a stereo mix. The stereo mix has both L and R channels. To capture that stereo image you need to record both L and R separately. This is not possible with the first suggestion of this answer, since the cable (not the interface) is merging L and R into one single signal. You can send mono to stereo just fine, but here we are sending stereo to stereo. That's the point.

Comment: @Dom Note that the RCA pair is coming from the mixer, and the TRS is going into the interface, not the other way around.

Comment: @JCPedroza The question is related to capturing a live mix of two mono guitars and a mono vocal.  Whenever I run a similar mixer in a live setting (what the OP is doing but wants to record) I have two main speakers to cover the entire audience.  Since only a small fraction of the audience would benefit from a stereo mix in a live setting, it is very uncommon to run a live mix in stereo.  So in a live mix, you would not pan part of the mix to left or right.  If you did, half the audience would miss half the mix.  If you just wanted to make a demo in stereo, whole different ballgame.

Comment: @RockinCowboy It depends on many things, like the venue, mixing engineer, speaker setup, etc, but panorama can (and often is) present in live mixes. Not all panning has to be hard left or hard right. Very subtle panning can help a voice cut through the mix better, without affecting the people located at the sides too much. Effects can add panorama too (and this mixer has aux send for that). The audience is not "missing half the mix". I heard Portishead live and the mix was in stereo, and it was an outstanding mix from wherever you heard it in the venue.

Comment: @RockinCowboy See this Karl Maciag blog: http://smart2noise.blogspot.mx/2012/04/karl-maciag-stereo-panning-in-live-mix.html "The moral of the story...pan as much as you want...but make sure everyone can hear it all. " He also suggests adding panorama through timbre. Another possibility is adding panorama through delay. You have many options here, and having the "mono only" dogma just limits them for no good reason.

Comment: @JCPedroza  I will check it out.  I am sure that with the right sound system in the right venue, stereo can be utilized in the mix to good effect.  With my Mackie 808S and two mains in small clubs, I have the option to use stereo - but all the sound engineers I know tell me I am better off in those circumstances running the mix in mono.  I will check out the blog you linked.  Thanks.

Comment: @JCPedroza - I Read the blog.  Very complex mixing scheme described to pan guitars - using two inputs for each instrument (ie two mics - pan one left the other right).  From the blog "Stereo is effective for recording, and listening with headphones or a nicely placed pair of stereo speakers.  In live sound, our goal is not so much to create an image, but rather to recreate what is happening on stage to every seat in the house."  and (about panning live mix)  "... effectively up to 2/3 of the audience could be robbed of what is happening on stage".  So your link reinforces my premise.

Comment: @JCPedroza To account for the possibility that some stereo effects might be used in a live mix, I edited the answer to show how you could capture a stereo effect for a recording of a live show.

Comment: @RockinCowboy It's a very simple setup and it's meant as an example of how some mixing engineers make use of panorama in live mixes, not as the only way it can be done. I never said you were wrong, if not done carefully panorama in a live setting can screw things up, that's not a secret. My point was that, regardless, panorama is still used in many scenarios and by many engineers, with care, and it can bring many benefits and widen your options. If you want to recluse yourself to one single dynamic so be it. We'll have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: @JCPedroza  - I will concede your point that it CAN be done.  I just don't think it's common - or I should say, I have not seen it done on anything less than a large arena or larger music venue setting with sophisticated sound reinforcement set up and knowledgeable sound engineers.  Blog mentioned that multiple inputs per instrument were a part of the equation.  Given the equipment cited by the OP -  (Hybrid SM802MS) it is not likely that this will be happening. But thanks for sharing what is possible with the right equipment.

Comment: @RockinCowboy Again, multiple inputs don't need to be part of the equation, it's just one example of how it can be done, not the only and definitive one. Live stereo mixes are more common than you might think, I feel like you are overly exaggerating your point for the sake of showing it. You don't have to go into sophisticated dynamics to be able to benefit from stereo mixes, or implement them. It not only can be done, It's done all the time with good results with equipment as simple as OP's.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my experience is to setup a stereo mic in a good sounding place in the room and record the sound. You will get the sound as the audience hears it, and a bit of the audience reaction as well. I would start high, possibly hanging from the roof and say 3 to 7 meters in front of stage. Not close to any wall or loudspeakers.

Catching the output from the PA mixer in my experience sounds simple does not give anything pleasant.

There are special stereo mics, or you could use on of the standard setups using two microphones. You record Left and Right signal.

The most used setup, and often a good start, is to use two cardiod condenser microphones. You point the business end of the mics towards the stage and put them a bit apart. A typical starting point may be the ORTF setup (named after the french state radio). It specifies 17 cm between the business ends (where the sound enters) and 110 degrees between the direction. It looks sort of weird the first time, but actually works. But you could be further apart with the mics, aiming for a say 30cm of a foot and a bit less angle. Google for DIN microphone setup.

Or simply try it out.